# How do I stop my bash shell from asking to install a package?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, fedora

When I mis-type a command, the shell tries to find a package that provides it.
How do I disable this feature?

Example:

```
[dave@dave cpp]$ sl
bash: sl: command not found...
Install package 'sl' to provide command 'sl'? [N/y]
```

I'd like if if I weren't prompted to install the command.

Comment: Wow, that seems annoying beyond reason! I know Ubuntu uses similar package suggestion, but at least it doesn't end in a prompt. Is this standard in Fedora Desktop? I run Fedora on a server and do not recognize it.

Comment: @DanielAndersson Fedora is the same, package `PackageKit-command-not-found`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is [PackageKitCommandNotFound](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/PackageKitCommandNotFound). Removing it

> yum remove PackageKit-command-not-found

should do the trick, according to the [mailing list](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/users/2011-October/405370.html).

Answer (score 5):

After doing a

```
yum remove PackageKit-command-not-found
```

if you get the error,

```
bash: /usr/libexec/pk-command-not-found: No such file or directory
```

you will need to add the follow line to ~/.bashrc

```
unset command_not_found_handle
```

Comment: Or log out and back in again. It's worth noting that unsetting `command_not_found_handle`  is sufficient even without removing the package.

Comment: @mattdm it's not sufficient, still need to remove that package.

Comment: @DominiCane It is. The bash procedure `command_not_found_handle` is defined in `/etc/profile.d/PackageKit.sh` (which belongs to package `PackageKit-command-not-found`). As long as you `unset` the variable for that procedure *after* `/etc/profile.d/PackageKit.sh`, it's fine. And that is done by adding a file that is run later than `PackageKit.sh`. As sorting is done by name, `xx_undoPackageKit.sh` in `/etc/profile.d` sounds good.